# Saving dynamic text box values to MySQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to save the data from dynamic text boxes from the cart textbox. My code is below. I am not able to save.

(32B TO 40B are textbox name and table column name)

```
global $con;    
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

    foreach($_POST['remove/update'] as $remove/update_id){
    $size_1 = $_POST['32B'];
    $size_2 = $_POST['34B'];
    $size_3 = $_POST['34C'];
    $size_4 = $_POST['36B'];
    $size_5 = $_POST['36C'];
    $size_6 = $_POST['38B'];
    $size_7 = $_POST['38C'];
    $size_8 = $_POST['40B'];

    $update_qty = "update cart set 32B='$size_1', 34B='$size_2', 34C='$size_3', 36B='$size_4', 36C='$size_5', 38B='$size_6', 38C='$size_7', 40B='$size_8'";
    mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

    echo $update_qty;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: are you getting somekind of errors?

Comment: use prepared statements pls..

Comment: No i am not getting any kind of error's but my concern is for exmple if i enter 40 qty's in size of 32B in every row in table it will update the same value(40 qty)..

Comment: can you share the form where the `$_POST` values are generated?

Comment: <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="32B" value="<?php echo $size_11; ?>">

Comment: Yeah plz @rst asked - Could u add before $update_qty these lines : print "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); print "</pre>"; And gave use the returned output.

Comment: Mr Falt4rm & RST   I got this below out put    Array
(
    [remove] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
        )

    [32B] => 0
    [34B] => 0
    [34C] => 0
    [36B] => 0
    [36C] => 0
    [38B] => 0
    [38C] => 0
    [40B] => 0
    [update_cart] => Update cart
)

1Array
(
    [remove] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
        )

    [32B] => 0
    [34B] => 0
    [34C] => 0
    [36B] => 0
    [36C] => 0
    [38B] => 0
    [38C] => 0
    [40B] => 0
    [update_cart] => Update cart
)

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` seems a little off. Without seeing the complete form I am not sure `$_POST['remove/update']` is correct, but if it is, this should work.

```
global $con;    
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

  foreach($_POST['remove'] as $update){
    $size_1 = $update['32B'];
    $size_2 = $update['34B'];
    $size_3 = $update['34C'];
    $size_4 = $update['36B'];
    $size_5 = $update['36C'];
    $size_6 = $update['38B'];
    $size_7 = $update['38C'];
    $size_8 = $update['40B'];

    $update_qty = "update cart set 32B='$size_1', 34B='$size_2', 34C='$size_3', 36B='$size_4', 36C='$size_5', 38B='$size_6', 38C='$size_7', 40B='$size_8'";
    mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);


    echo $update_qty;

  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Please, remove your answers and add anything relevant to your question.

Comment: I agree with RST, +1. Nice top answer btw. :)